# Dynamically set attribute key (e.g. data-{foo}="bar") in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, skrollr

Setting an attribute in React is straightforward if you know the key, e.g.

`data-500={this.props.YDistance}`

but how can one dynamically set part of the key. e.g.

`data-{this.props.YDistance}="valueHere"`

```
var Test = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div data-{this.props.YDistance}="valueHere">
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }

});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Test YDistance="500">Hello World!</Test>,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

There are libraries that require this kind of attribute setting (e.g. [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/]) et al)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use an object to store the dynamic properties and then use JSX spread attributes.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html

```
const propBag = { [`data-${foo}`] = 'bar' };
return (
  <div {...propBag}>
     {this.props.children}
  </div>
);
```

That is using the [computed properties](http://es6-features.org/#ComputedPropertyNames) feature of ES6 as well as [template literal strings](http://es6-features.org/#StringInterpolation).  If you are not using ES6 features you could do an ES5 implementation like so:

```
var propBag = {};
propBag['data-' + foo] = 'bar';
return (
  <div {...propBag}>
     {this.props.children}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: This can be further simplified inline with [computed keys](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer): `<div {...{['data-' + foo]: 'bar'}}>...</div>`.

Comment: Thanks @ctrlplusb - great solution! Small edit... should the first line read `const propBag = { [`data-${foo}`] : 'bar' };` ?

Comment: No problem.  :)  It's not a typo no.  Look into those links that I provided underneath the code example.  It's some magic ES6 syntax being used.  Don't worry, it's not too magic, if you go through a couple of examples you'll quickly grasp them.  :)

Comment: @EdWilliams You are right, but you don't need even square bracket: `const propBag = { \`data-${foo}\`: 'bar' };` is a valid syntax!

Comment: i am storing attributes into the object and then using spread operator but its giving unexpected token issue for this.state.atributes