# react-grid-layout example Unknown prop `_grid` on <div> tag

Tags: reactjs, react-grid-layout

I'm trying to implement `react-grid-layout`. All of the examples pass the grid item configuration through a `_grid` div property:

```
createElement(el) {
  ...
  return (
    <div key={i} _grid={el}>
      ...
    </div>
  );
},
```

In my implementation:

```
return (
  <div key={i} _grid={el}>
    <DashboardTestWidget widgetName={el.name} menuName={this.props.menuName}/>
    <span className="remove" style={removeStyle} onClick={this.onRemoveItem.bind(this, i)}>x</span>
  </div>
)
```

I get an error:

```
dashboard_view.browserify.browserified.js:1216 Warning: Unknown prop `_grid` on <div> tag. Remove this prop from the element. For details, see <URL ommitted because SO complained about URL shorteners>
  in div (created by DashboardLayout)
  in Resizable (created by GridItem)
  in DraggableCore (created by GridItem)
  in GridItem (created by ReactGridLayout)
  in div (created by ReactGridLayout)
  in ReactGridLayout (created by ResponsiveReactGridLayout)
  in ResponsiveReactGridLayout (created by _class)
  in _class (created by DashboardLayout)
  in div (created by DashboardLayout)
  in DashboardLayout
```

I'm fairly new to React. What am I doing wrong?

---

Relevant `npm` package versions I use:

```
"react": "^15.2.1",
"react-dom": "^15.2.1",
"react-grid-layout": "^0.12.7",
```

Comment: https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout/issues/283

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a change that React made to their code base around May this year. See [this pull request](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/6800) for more information on this.

The reason you are getting this error is because you are trying to render a none HTML recognised attribute.

In HTML5 you need to define custom attributes using `data-*`.

To prevent the warning from showing in your case, you will have to change your render method to this.

```
return (
    <div key={i} data-grid={el}>
        <DashboardTestWidget widgetName={el.name} menuName={this.props.menuName}/>
        <span className="remove" style={removeStyle} onClick={this.onRemoveItem.bind(this, i)}>x</span>
    </div>
);
```

Note that `_grid` has been changed to `data-grid` which react will now recognise as a valid HMTL attribute.

One thing to note with React is that it will allow you to pass custom props to custom components, but when you render those components to HTML, they need to be valid HTML attributes.

Comment: Changing `_grid` to `data-grid` made the error go away, but now the `h` and `w` I set for each `el` don't seem to apply and all dashboard item shrinks to `1x1` on load. This will be the good direction just the framework has to pick up the `w` and `h` (and other attributes).

Comment: Hmmm, in the debugger I see `data-grid="[object Object]"`. I guess I have to JSON serialize?

Comment: Even if I JSON stringify, `data-grid="{"i":"0","x":0,"y":0,"w":6,"h":4,"add":false,"name":"react_test_bar_graph"}"` is not picked up

Comment: Tried also `var propBag = { 'data-grid': `{x: ${el.x}, y: ${el.y}, w: ${el.w}, h: ${el.h}}` };` and then `<div key={i} {...propBag}>`.

Comment: The only way I could get it to work is: `var propBag = { '_grid': el };` and then `<div key={i} {...propBag}>`. It's a mystery looking at this why  `<div key={i} _grid={el}>` doesn't work. I'll either write an own answer or you can correct yours if you think it's acceptable.

Comment: Actually, I still see the warning, but at least it's working.

Comment: I don't mark this answer, because changing it to data-grid prevents the widget item data to reach the framework. Using _grid causes a warning but things still work

Comment: Looks like a commit retired _grid and now uses data-grid. So pretty soon your answer will be correct. https://github.com/vpezeshkian/react-grid-layout/commit/d35e24754b13f8d8223a2b37ae72162fe08c880c

Comment: The new react-grig-layout now doesn't have this